# Splitting read file C++

Tags: c++

Lets start with that I have absolutely no experience with C++ , but I got this project to connect a POS with a verifone. We do not have the standard verifone SDK but something custom.

At fist I needed to prepair data to send to C++ and C++ will send it to the Verifone. This is where I am getting stuck, I have a .txt file, which I can read with C++ but now I need to split the data.

This is my current code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string file_get_contents(const char *filename)
{
    ifstream in(filename);
    if (in.fail())
    {
        cerr << "File not found: " << filename << endl;
        return "";
    }

    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << in.rdbuf();
    in.close();
    return buffer.str();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    vector<string> strings;

    string contents = file_get_contents("C:/wamp/www/cmd/config.txt");

    string s;
    while (contents, s, '||') {
        cout << s << endl;
        strings.push_back(s);
    }

    cout << s;  // ECHO CONTENTS
    std::cin.ignore();  // pause
    return 0;
}
```

With this code my console just stays blank, no data is being displayed.
The full string I am splitting is:

```
"notepad://amount=10320.53||session_id=7946548443287465/"
```

The result that I want is to get an array that uses "amount" and  "session_id" as keys and their values as value.

What is the best way of achieving this?

I used the following code to actually display the string in my console which was working:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string contents = file_get_contents("config.txt");
    cout << contents;   // ECHO CONTENTS
    std::cin.ignore();  // pause
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: What kind of C++ version are you using? If you use C++11, you can use [regular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).

Comment: `while (contents, s, '||')` what is this condition supposed to do?

Comment: You're not actually reading anything in to your ifstream, just getting its buffer

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz It's supposed to split the string at the "||" characters to my first attempt to get closer to the result I want to achieve.

Comment: @Schrieveslaach I am using C++ 11

Comment: @killstreet: It's easier to say that this is not the appropriate way to tokenize a string than it is to explain what's actually happening in that while() condition. Google methods for string tokenization or string splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to use a regex to extract the information you want, there are a lot of online resources on how to read files properly so I left that part out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::regex pattern("amount=([[:digit:]\\.]*)\\|\\|session_id=([[:digit:]]*)");
    std::smatch results;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> data;

    std::string contents = "notepad://amount=10320.53||session_id=7946548443287465/";
    //string contents = file_get_contents("C:/wamp/www/cmd/file.txt");
    if(std::regex_search(contents, results, pattern))
    {
        data["amount"] = results[1];
        data["session_id"] = results[2];
    }
    std::cout << "Amount: " <<  data["amount"] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Seesion ID: " << data["session_id"] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @killstreet That's weird, this code doesn't access files or anything outside of itself

Comment: This line : if(std::regex_search(contents, results, pattern)) is causing the error to occure, trying to check why it would do this.

Comment: The type of virus being shown by Norman is "Virus: Gen:Variant.Kazy.729635" Not sure how much this might help?

Comment: @killstreet you can tell your antivirus that it's a false positive, not sure why it would think that `std::regex_search()` is a virus

Comment: Alright the code is working, thank you very very much. I will have some more look into why this is being detected as a virus, just in case there isn't much to find, would there be another simple way of achieving the same result??

Comment: @killstreet yes, you can use `std::string::find` to parse the string appropriately, I can't think of an elegant way to do it right now though

Comment: We decided to add an exeption on our clients computer for this particular folder, many thanks for your help!